# Preseeding Dual boot dual hard drives Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, preseed

First post here. Just wondering if anyone can help. I'm not Linux expert or anything so this may just be my brain frazzling!

Ok, so I'm using the same hardware and same method I have been using with 16.04.x which all worked fine. I am using a fairly new pc with two nvme hard drives in (one 500gb and one 250gb).
In my preseed file under partitioning I specify the 250gb disk (d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/nvme1n1) for Ubuntu as Windows goes on nvme0n1 (the 500gb disk).
My auto deployment/installation of Ubuntu works fine for a few times but then suddenly i'll find that for some reason its installed itself onto the 500gb disk instead of the 250gb?! If i then look in gparted or do lsblk the disk labels have swapped over so now the 250gb disk appears as nvme0n1 instead of nvme1n1 and the 500gb appears as nvme1n1 instead of nvme0n1. If I reboot then usually the labels have switched back to how they should be but obviously Ubuntu has now written over the windows 500gb disk.
When i deploy Windows 10 via sccm it will consistently deploy to the 500gb disk (disk 0)
Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Currently i've sort of given up on this and am waiting for 18.04.2 to see if that fixes anything.
Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got round this myself so I'll post what I did in case anyone else needs it.
In the preseed I was able to use a partman early command that queries the attached disks for their total size and then uses awk to extract the name of the drive:

```
d-i partman/early_command string debconf-set partman-auto/disk /dev/"$(lsblk -lnb | awk '$4==256060514304' | awk '{print $1}')"
```